# How to match first child of an element only if it's not preceeded by a text node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I'm trying to match the h4 of a div (using jQuery) so that I can remove it's top margin.  However, I only want to match the h4 if it has no text on top of it.  For example, match this:

```
<div>
  <h4>Header</h4>
  ...
</div>
```

but not this:

```
<div>
  Blah blah blah.
  <h4>Header</h4>
  ...
</div>
```

The best code I could come up with in jQuery is this:

```
$("div h4:first-child")
```

But that, unfortunately, matches both the above cases.  Is there anyway to specify that you want it to be the absolute first element, with no text nodes before it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>
    <h4>Header</h4>
    ...
</div>

<div>
    Blah blah blah.
    <h4>Header</h4>
    ...
</div>
```

then you could use the following.

```
$('div').each(function() {
    var me = this;
    if ($(me).html().toUpperCase().indexOf("<H4>") == 0){ //check to see if the inner html starts with an h4 tag
        $(me).children('h4')... //do what you need to do to the header
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no guarantee that the text above the h4 will be a `<span>`. It might just be a naked text node.

Comment: Cameron - what is stopping you from putting the text in a span or a div or a p?

Comment: maybe you could use the .html() value to check the contents of the html. if the .html() value starts with '<h4>' then you will know that you have a match

Comment: Russell - I'm not in complete control of the HTML.  Users can modify it through a web form.

Comment: I have changed my if statement above to check to see if the inner html starts with an <h4> tag or not. maybe that will work for you?

Comment: i just tested in IE7 and it works. you may want to do a trim on the inner html returned by .html() to make sure there is no whitespace.

Comment: That should probably work too... except I'm thinking you'd probably want `$(me).children('h4:first-child')` or else you might get extra h4 elements (if there was more than one in that div).

Comment: I think it might be more efficient to maybe match all the divs with h4:first-child, then do the same thing you did except using `.parent().html()...`.

Comment: I'm voting down for answer theft :)

Comment: definitely have a bunch of options to play around with. I'm glad it has helped you out though. good luck!

Comment: fyi, there is a $.trim() jQuery utility function that could be handy to trim that string.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("div h4")
    .filter(function() {
    var prev = this.previousSibling;
        return (!prev 
            || prev.nodeType !== 3
            || (prev.nodeType == 3 && prev.nodeValue.match(/^\s*$/)));
    })
```

Edit: Fixed it. Works in Firefox, IE8

Notes:

1. 'this' inside the filter function refers to node

   both H4s have a text node before them. I think browsers insert text nodes everywhere they find whitespace and line break. In this case we select only the ones that are not whitespace-only.

   `Node.TEXT_NODE` is not available in IE. Hence using the magic number 3.

Comment: I just tested it... no dice.  It still matches both cases (in Firefox at least).

Comment: Botched up the filter function. I'm fixing it.