# How can I tell if a jQuery node is at the beginning of its parent node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Given the following HTML:

```
<p><img id="one" alt="at beginning, return true" />Some Text</p>
<p>Some <img id="two" alt="in middle, return false" />Text</p>
<p>Some Text<img id="three" alt="at end, return false" /></p>
```

How would I be able to tell that `$("img#one")` is at the beginning of its parent node?

Ideally what I'm trying to do is this:

```
$("p>img").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent();
    if ("$this is at the beginning of $parent.html()") {
        $parent.before($this);
    } else {
        $parent.after($this);
    }
});
```

**Edit:** with [sebasgo's help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144384/how-can-i-tell-if-a-jquery-node-is-at-the-beginning-of-its-parent-node/1144418#1144418), here's the final code and result:

```
$("p>img").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent();
    if (this == this.parentNode.firstChild) {
        $parent.before($this);
    } else {
        $parent.after($this);
    }
});

<img id="one" alt="at beginning, return true" />
<p>Some Text</p>
<p>Some Text</p>
<img id="two" alt="in middle, return false" />
<p>Some Text</p>
<img id="three" alt="at end, return false" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var elem = $("img#one").get(0)
if (elem.parentNode.firstChild == elem)
{ .... }
```

Hope this works better.

Comment: As I see jQuery ignores text nodes in its selector engine. Then you schould use plain javascript:

var elem = document.getElementById("#one");

if (elem == elem.parentNode.firstChild) {...}

Comment: perfect thanks! since I'm in a .each() I went with (this == this.parentNode.firstChild)

Answer (score 2):

The following code will tell you if the node in question is the 'first-child' or not so should work for you. I've just been battling with a similar problem and this worked for me.

```
if($(this).prev().length)
{
    // Not first-child
} else {
    // is first-child
}
```

Comment: That doesn't take text nodes into account though.

Comment: Ah yes, maybe it wont help you! The text is not actually a child of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try this condition:

```
($parent.contents().eq(0).attr("id") === $this.attr("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

From similar question on SO.

[How to match first child of an element only if it's not preceeded by a text node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562134/jquery-how-to-match-first-child-of-an-element-only-if-its-not-preceeded-by-a-te)

```
$("p>img").each(function () {
    var prev = this.previousSibling;
    var isThisTheFirstNode = $(this).parent().html().toUpperCase().indexOf('<IMG>') == 0;

    var method = isThisTheFirstNode ? 'before' : 'after';
    $(this).parent[method].before(this);
});
```